# TeamCity - New lines in setParameter

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to use setParameter in a PowerShell step to set a parameter that must be newline separated.

I am using a command similar to this:

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='name' value='$val']"
```

Having actual newlines in the PowerShell variable does not work as it resolves like this:

```
"##teamcity[setParameter name='name' value='val1
val2']"
```

I tried adding "\n" and this did not get interpreted as a new line:

```
"##teamcity[setParameter name='name' value='val1\nval2']"
```

Is there a way to include new lines or a way to append a new line to an existing parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Guilherme Barbosa, the answer is to use pipe as an escape character:

```
"##teamcity[setParameter name='name' value='val1|nval2']"
```

https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4529790815506-PowerShell-Step-New-lines-in-setParameter